# How to remove inside of a string from a list of words that have start/end delimiter?

Tags: python, regex

Looking to remove parts of string from the middle with predefined list of words that have a delimiter.

```
delimiter_begin = "#"
delimiter_end = "@"
remove_list = ["#ab", "O@"]
string = "abc ab . bb, cc O cbaO"
```

```
for s in remove_list:
    if delimiter_begin in s:
        replace_begin = s.replace(delimiter_begin, "")
        for e in remove_list:
            if delimiter_end in e:
                replace_end = e.replace(delimiter_end, "")
                string = re.sub(fr"(\b{replace_begin}\b).*(\b{replace_end}\b)", "", string)
                print(string)
```

```
abc  cbaO
```

This gets the desired output as but I am wondering if there is a better way of doing this?

Another problem arises when a regex special character should be parsed out. As example when replacing remove_list and string:

```
remove_list = ["#ab", "?@"]
string = "abc ab . bb, cc ? cba abc"
```

I get a re.error: nothing to repeat. How can I escape these characters?

Comment: You can escape characters by adding a backslash, e.g. `\.`

Comment: It is not clear what the input in real life looks like. If there is always two elements in `remove_list`, it is more or less easy then. Of course, if the strings can be non-word, then you can't use word boundaries, and you need to `re.escape` the "words", but you need to clear out the use of delimiters.

Comment: Yes there may be random non-word strings, but this sort of removal from inside of string shouldn't happen more than once in a string. I think str.split is less complicated. Thanks for the input though!